# SQL query to count based on MM-YYYY part of date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to show count of job application for last 12 months based on & need to group them also based on Job Application dates

I tried following it generates error as shown below.

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(MONTH(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Total, 
   ApplicationDate 
FROM 
   [Jobs] 
GROUP BY 
   ApplicationDate, ApplicationDate 
ORDER BY
   ApplicationDate
```

But that resulted in an error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
>   'COUNT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

I need it for SQL Server 2008

Final Working solution

```
SELECT   
MONTH(ApplicationDate),   YEAR(ApplicationDate),   COUNT(*) AS Total, 
    (CAST(MONTH(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(4)))  as ApplicationDate
    FROM    [Jobs] 
GROUP BY    YEAR(ApplicationDate),   MONTH(ApplicationDate)

ORDER BY
       YEAR(ApplicationDate),   MONTH(ApplicationDate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one?

```
 SELECT 
       COUNT(*) AS Total, 
       (CAST(MONTH(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(4)))  as ApplicationDate 
    FROM 
       [Jobs]  
    GROUP BY 
       (CAST(MONTH(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(4))) 
    ORDER BY
      ApplicationDate
```

the cast function was missing for month. Output will be as follows.

```
Total   ApplicationDate
22217   7-2012
17979   8-2012
30341   9-2012
```

Edited for sorting...

If you are not particular about the 'MM-YYYY' format. Convert the month/year combination to number and order by that. Try this.

```
 SELECT 
   COUNT(*) AS Total, 
   RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ApplicationDate, 103), 7)  as ApplicationDate, 
   CAST(REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ApplicationDate, 103), 7), '/', '') as int) as numdate
FROM 
   [Jobs] 
GROUP BY 
   RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ApplicationDate, 103), 7)
ORDER BY
  numdate,ApplicationDate
```

Comment: It is not getting desired multiple result for MM-YYYY, It show 1 2012-09-21
`1 2013-09-01
2 2013-09-06
2 2013-09-08
1 2013-09-09
3 2013-09-11
1 2013-09-19
1 2013-09-21
2 2013-09-22
15 2013-09-24
1 2013-09-26
2 2013-10-06
1 2013-12-11
1 2013-12-12`

Comment: Ray, I actually need to show this on line chart count of job application for last 12 months for this i need to correct order.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker plz chk this

Comment: This will also work but i found Other apraoc based on `Marc_s` solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to try something like this to get one row for each month/year that contains the count of applications for that month/year:

```
SELECT
   MONTH(ApplicationDate),
   YEAR(ApplicationDate),
   COUNT(*)
FROM 
   dbo.[Jobs] 
GROUP BY 
   YEAR(ApplicationDate),
   MONTH(ApplicationDate)
ORDER BY
   YEAR(ApplicationDate),
   MONTH(ApplicationDate)
```

This counts the applications per month / year and groups by it, too. You should get an output something like this:

[image]

(*this is taken from the `AdventureWorks` sample database*)

If you do a `GROUP BY ApplicationDate`, then you're basically grouping / counting by the actual **date** itself (not it's month/year parts)

**Update:** if you **must** have SQL Server provide the formatting in the `MM-YYYY` format (really should be done in your web app and not by SQL Server), then try this:

```
;WITH GroupedData AS
(
    SELECT
       DateMonth = MONTH(ApplicationDate),
       DateYear = YEAR(ApplicationDate),
       JobsCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM 
       dbo.[Jobs]
    GROUP BY 
       YEAR(ApplicationDate),
       MONTH(ApplicationDate)
)
SELECT
    RIGHT('00' + CAST(DateMonth AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '-' +
    CAST(DateYear AS VARCHAR(4)),
    JobsCount 
FROM 
    GroupedData
ORDER BY
    DateMonth, DateYear
```

Comment: so far your query is getting the correct result but i cant use it as i need another column which show MM-YYYY, i tried but it gives me errors or gets wrong result. How can i modify it with our effect result.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: updated my response to include your formatting needs

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT  DATENAME(month,ApplicationDate) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(year,ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
        COUNT(1) TotalCnt
FROM    dbo.[Jobs] 
GROUP BY DATENAME(month,ApplicationDate) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(year,ApplicationDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
```